# Android socket client get reply from server

Tags: android, sockets

I'm new in socket. I really need your help.
I have create a socket client in android, and send the server a picture successfully. The next task what I want to do is receiving a JSON file from the server as the reply. However, after I close the outstream, it always tell me, " Socket is closed".

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//write out the stream
out.close();
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
//!!it always throws SocketException, and tell me socket is closed
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
int temp = 0;
// read data from inputStream
while ((temp = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, temp));
}
```

I have tried many ways to solve it.
1.close the outstream lately

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//write out the stream
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
int temp = 0;
//!!My client seems to wait for some messages from server.
//However, since I didn't close the outputStream, the server can't stop writing the file from my outputStream.
//As a result, the server can't send back JSON file to me as a reply.
//My server and client all go blocked.
while ((temp = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, temp));
}
out.close();
```

2.connect the socket again

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//write out the stream
out.close();
socket.connect(sc_add,2000);
//!!it will tell me the socket is already connected this time
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
//it always throws SocketException, and tell me socket is closed
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
int temp = 0;
// read data from inputStream
while ((temp = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, temp));
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `/However, since I didn't close the outputStream, the server can't stop writing the file from my outputStream.`. Do you mean that the server then does not stop reading from its inputstream?

Comment: You should make your own file transfer protocol. Send first the lenth of the file. Then the server knows how many bytes are coming and will not try to read more bytes than that file size.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your reply. Can't the server just return another file by this socket, like a feedback?

Comment: The server is just trying to read and read because you told it to do so. So the server is not returning anything as it continues to read and read. I said that before.

Comment: Well, I close this socket, and I create a ServerSocket to get the JSON. Howerver, I get "connection timeout".

Comment: Well that strategy will not work as you have seen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I send the length of the file to the server, and it can do the next step with this information after we solved some bothering problem.

Comment: Finally, we found out the logical error in our code on the server side. It read 4 bits lesser than we needed.